# Connect / disconnect unknown postfix log

Tags: centos, postfix, smtp

I'm checking the logs and i found these lines in maillog

```
postfix/smtpd[12135]: warning: hostname mta9.imxonlines.co.za does not resolve to address 91.212.150.89: Name or service not known

connect from unknown[91.212.150.89]
disconnect from unknown[91.212.150.89]
```

I'm seeing these lines constantly. Is this any kind of smtp attack?
If yes then how can i prevent these from connecting and disconnecting?

Comment: You can set up fail2ban if you haven't already. Apart from that you can only ignore it. Welcome to the internet.

Comment: How can i setup fail2ban? only for sasl auth